why zookeeper creates znode multiple times
Analysis of the ZooKeeper transaction log (version-2/log.1) reveals a pattern where a znode is initially created, subsequently deleted after a 3-second interval, and then recreated approximately 5 minutes later
12/23/24 8:15:10 AM IRST session 0x10000506cd4012a cxid 0x1 zxid 0x2ca create /ansible_test,sample,[31,s{'world,'anyone}
],false,60
12/23/24 8:15:12 AM IRST session 0x10000506cd4012b cxid 0x0 zxid 0x2cb createSession 30000
12/23/24 8:15:13 AM IRST session 0x10000506cd4012c cxid 0x0 zxid 0x2cc createSession 30000
12/23/24 8:15:13 AM IRST session 0x10000506cd4012c cxid 0x1 zxid 0x2cd delete '/ansible_test

after 5 minuts
12/23/24 8:20:10 AM IRST session 0x10000506cd4012e cxid 0x1 zxid 0x2d4 create /ansible_test,sample,[31,s{'world,'anyone}
],false,61
12/23/24 8:20:12 AM IRST session 0x10000506cd4012f cxid 0x0 zxid 0x2d5 createSession 30000
12/23/24 8:20:13 AM IRST session 0x10000506cd40130 cxid 0x0 zxid 0x2d6 createSession 30000
12/23/24 8:20:13 AM IRST session 0x10000506cd40130 cxid 0x1 zxid 0x2d7 delete '/ansible_test

I was able to access that znode within only 3 seconds. Why does ZooKeeper behave this way? How can I create a persistent znode?
